# Create a new record with certain values after updating an existing record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table "Payments" in Access 2013. It has the following fields

DatePaid
DueDate
LeaseID

What I am trying to do is this:

When "DatePaid" is updated via a Form I need to create a new record in the "Payments" table with the same "LeaseID" as the one in the Form and fill in "DueDate" with the same day of the following month.

For example:

In the Table (Before Update) --

```
Record  LeaseID    DueDate   DatePaid
------  -------  ---------  --------- 
     1      123  11/5/2013
```

On the Form ---

```
LeaseID: 123

DatePaid: 11/4/2013

[Submit]
```

Need the Table to Do This (After Form Entry) --

```
Record  LeaseID    DueDate   DatePaid
------  -------  ---------  ---------
     1      123  11/5/2013  11/4/2013
     2      123  12/5/2013
```

Comment: *Same Day but Next The Month* can be quite complicated. For example do you need to make business day adjustments? Also what about dates that don't exist in the following month. For example 10/31. Should the next month be 11/30 or 12/1?

Comment: Good point!! I didn't think of that. I will need to check with them for that answer. I'll get back to you on that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Access 2013 you could try using a Data Macro and see if it does the trick. Open the [Payments] table in Design View and choose `Create Data Macros` > `After Update` from the ribbon:

[image: AfterUpdate.png]

Then add the following macro steps

[image: DataMacro.png]

Now, whenever the [DatePaid] field gets filled in the Data Macro will create another record in that table for the following month.

Note that if you have the table open in Datasheet View and fill in a [DatePaid] value you will need to click `Refresh All` on the `Home` tab of the ribbon (or hit <kbd>F5</kbd>) to see the new record.